# Convert TestNG Start and Stop time to Postgres Without Time Zone

Tags: postgresql, testng, reporting

I currently have some TestNG custom reporting code that works with the local MySQL database I have been testing against.  The resulting database is postgres due to issues with latest MySQL versions in AWS, in trying to convert the format of TestNG millis over I have been encountering issues with the format which I can't seem to get one that works right.

My custom report code was using the following:

```
report.reporting.put("startDate", testResult.getStartMillis());
report.reporting.put("endDate", testResult.getEndMillis());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
String startDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("startDate"));
String endDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("endDate"));
```

When I try some of the dateformatters I am receiving indexing errors like:  DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 4

I've used some various options like offset or instant with no success.

This is a collection of some of the options I have tried.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
    String startDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("startDate"));
    String endDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("endDate"));

    // OffsetDateTime startDbTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(startRawDbTime);
    // OffsetDateTime endDbTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(endRawDbTime);
    // ZonedDateTime startDbTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(startRawDbTime);
    // ZonedDateTime endDbTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(endRawDbTime);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
    String startRawDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("startDate"));
    String endRawDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("endDate"));
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
    LocalDate startParse = LocalDate.parse(startRawDbTime,formatter);
    LocalDate endParse = LocalDate.parse(endRawDbTime,formatter);
    Long startTimeRaw = Long.parseLong(report.get("startDate").toString());
    Instant startInst = Instant.ofEpochMilli(startTimeRaw);
    ZonedDateTime zoneStart = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(startInst, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    LocalDate dateStart = formatter.format(zoneStart);
```

Is there a conversion step I am missing?  I thought it would be simple to convert from millis to something that postgres would accept.

Answer (score 0):

Worked out how to do this with PostGres by resetting the DB table to be a date with time zone, then adjusted my Java code to the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String startRawDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("startDate"));
String endRawDbTime = sdf.format(report.get("endDate"));
Timestamp timeStart = Timestamp.valueOf(startRawDbTime);
Timestamp timeEnd = Timestamp.valueOf(endRawDbTime);
```

With the statement insert updated with the right type:

```
    reportInsert.setObject(4,timeStart, Types.TIMESTAMP);
    reportInsert.setObject(5,timeEnd, Types.TIMESTAMP);
```

Everything works as expected now.